# htaccess create a new rewriterule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a rewrite rule that transforms a specific URL to a different one.

URL: `http://www.example.com/index.php?r=site/action&param1=value1`

Desired result: `http://www.example.com/value1`

The htaccess that I'm trying is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php\?r=site/action&param1=([a-zA-Z])$ $1 [L]
```

But this doesn't work. Could you help me please?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP please do not abuse tags. What is the point of site/action if you are just getting ride of this value? this may be of some assistance although your question is a little different http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873223/a-htaccess-php-templating-system/25873323#25873323

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?r=site/action&param1=$1 [L,QSA]
```